# Need to know who connected to the server

Tags: windows-server-2008

In my company, we have a server that needs to run several tasks and need a user to be logged on (despite my requests to change those procedures).
To complicate even more, several users have access to this account.
So, sometimes, someone have the great idea to logoff the account session.

Now I need to know to know who did it. On event viewer I can only see which account has made the logoff an when, but I need to find out which user did it, by knowing which computer name or ip made the connection on the server.

Is there a way to get this info? If so, where?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 1):

> several users have access to this account
>
> sometimes, someone have the great idea to logoff the account session.

You have a couple of options:

1. You simply **ASK** the users that have access to the account who logged off the session.  They could lie like children, but it is straight and to the point.
2. You can prevent logoff via GPO on that server (Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ Start Menu and Taskbar \ Remove Logoff on the Start Menu) if you so desire.

Honestly, it's already not an ideal setup for security to begin with, so anything you do at this point is just going to be internal communication among those involved or #2 above.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You could try to trace the machines from the logon events in the event log - but that will be time consuming, and as you say - it is already uselesss as it is not granular enough.

At the end, if you put a SERIOUS amount of effort into having procedures that are unreasonable from a security point of view, you can expect to be successfull and have a serious security and auditing problem. And this is what happened. Inform the powers to be that basically if you insist on not tracking this, do not come back and ask why it was not tracked or demand it to be tracked.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your logging level, and from the sounds of it, your logging level may not be sufficient.  We audit logon events (granular-level logging for logon events), so I can see events like the below in my servers' Security Event Logs.

[image]

So, based on the logon time, account name and IP recorded by the audit logging, I can trace a logon based on time, and determine which user did it, and from where.  (In this case, it was me, from my workstation.)  I would correlate the timing of the logoff with these `Audit Success` events to come up with "who did it."

[If you don't have this level of logging, it might be time to consider enabling it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787567%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), for next time, because the way you're set up, there will be a next time...

Which brings up the point that this setup is not ideal.  If you need an account to stay logged on, you need to be making sure that happens through your configuration and policy.  You're not exactly clear on what happened/precisely how the log off occurred, so I'm not going to speculate at how best to prevent it in the future, but there are easy technical or policy solutions to these problems, and it sounds like its high time you implement one.